# Generate a geometry column from latitude and longitude columns with SQL

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, sql, dbmanager

My table has the columns latitude and longitude in float8 type.
I want to generate a geometry column from these two columns.
I make the following query in the SQL Window of the DB Manager in QGIS.

```sql
ALTER TABLE populated_places
ADD geographyColumn AS geography::STGeomFromText('POINT('+convert(varchar(20),latitude)+' 'convert(varchar(20),longitude)+')',4326)
```

I get the following error: `syntax error at or near "AS"`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Your statement looks like a random chain of SQL related commands, **or a MySQL/MS SQL Server command (see @ConcreteGannet's answer)**, so in accordance with your questions tags, the *actual* solution to this issue is likely to properly introduce yourself to the **PostgreSQL** dialect, and the **PostGIS** extension.

---

The correct set of commands would be to

1. add the `geom` column of type `GEOMETRY`, and register the *typemod* constraints `(POINT, 4326)` to the system catalogues:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE populated_places
     ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY(POINT, 4326)
   ;
   ```
2. fill the new column with actual geometries

   ```
    UPDATE populated_places
      SET  geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)
    ;
   ```
3. create a spatial index covering your new geometries [*optional, but highly recommended*]

   ```
   CREATE INDEX ON populated_places
     USING GIST (geom)
   ;
   ```
4. update table statistics for the query planner [*optional, but highly recommended*]

   ```
   VACUUM ANALYZE populated_places;
   ```

Comment: I think the original question is fine in Microsoft SQL Server, and CONVERT is not an ISO standard SQL function, so if I had to bet I'd say it is SQL Server and not Postgres.

Comment: @ConcreteGannet and indeed I thought as much...but I have to work with whatever OP cares to share in terms of information right. I added a note about this, though.

Comment: I take it back! float8 isn't an MSSQL data type. Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a plus character between the literal space and the second call to the convert function. I added spaces either side of the plus operators, which I think helps one spot the problem.

My suggested complete statement:

ALTER TABLE populated_places
ADD geographyColumn AS geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + convert(varchar(20),latitude) + ' ' + convert(varchar(20),longitude) + ')',4326)

My change in bold below:
... ' ' **+** convert(...